# Cannot assign a rig bone to a mesh

Tags: vertex-groups

Import a figure from Makehuman.
Import a STL hat.
Select the hat mesh in edit mode and when I go to Data vertex groups my rig bones are not listed.
How do I get the rig vertex groups to show so I can assign the hat to the head bone??

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your hat is a new object, by default it has no reason to have any vertex group as you haven't parented to the armature yet. There are several solutions, one would be to join the hat to the body (select the hat, shift select the body and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>J</kbd>), then, now that the hat is part of the body mesh, select the hat vertices, select the vertex group it is supposed to be assigned to in the *Vertex Groups* list, and click on the *Assign* button.

Comment: Thank you very much, sorted.